# Display Back button to go back like the browser back button when not in home path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

In the header, I have a **menu button**, that when clicked will display different links to go to. However, I would only like to show the menu button when its in the home path (i.e., "/"). And when I navigate to other pages, I would like to change the the menu button to **back button**. This back button  should be like the browser back button which will go back one step at a time, till I get back to the home path. How can I achieve this? I am using "react": "^15.1.0" and "react-router": "^2.5.2".

AppClient.js

```
ReactDom.render((
    <Router history={hashHistory} >
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <IndexRoute component={Home} />
            <Route path="home" component={Home}/>
            ...
            ...
            <Route path="profile" component={Profile}>
                <IndexRoute component={Timeline} />
                <Route path="timeline" component={Timeline}/>
        </Route>
        <Route path="login" component={Login}/>
    </Router>
  ), reactContainer)
```

App.js

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const _this = this;
        return (
            <div>
                <Header/>
                ...
                ...
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Header.js

```
export default class Header extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <header>
                <div id="header-wrapper">
                    <div id="nav-bar-btn" class="nav">

                        // change Menu when its not home path that is "/"
                        <Menu>
                        // to Back
                        <Back>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: Use  `<input type="button" value="Back" onclick="history.go(-1);" />`

Comment: This is HTML syntax..

Comment: if you are using redux too, then you'll get a router through props and then you can simple check for the router.location.pathname use ternary operator to mount the `<Menu />` or `<Back />` component. Other wise you'll have to listen for route change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2fmbfn41/2/)**

```
import { hashHistory } from 'react-router';

export default class Header extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={showBack:location.hash.split('?')[0]!=="#/"};
        this.hook = hashHistory.listenBefore(loc=>
            this.setState({showBack:loc.pathname!=="/"})
        );
    }
    componentWillUnmount(){
        this.hook(); //unlisten
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <header>
                <div id="header-wrapper">
                    <div id="nav-bar-btn" class="nav">
                        {this.state.showBack?
                         <div onClick={()=>hashHistory.goBack()}>Go BACK</div> 
                          : <Menu/>
                         }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
        );
    }
}
```

`listenBefore` watches path, and decides whether show button or not.

And `hashHistory.goBack()`, works like browser back button

[image]

Comment: Excellent answer but could you please update your answer by demonstrating how to do this in `react-router v4`

Comment: Cannot read property 'listenBefore' of undefined this error I'm getting

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the **router** to your context (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html).

```
Header.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
```

*react-router* will normally populate the **this.context.router** variable.

With this **this.context.router** object, there's a lot of methods available, like **goBack()** (https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#goback).